# Automatic backup of Google Compute Instance for easy restore

Tags: instance, google-compute-engine, restore, snapshot

I'm using Google Compute Instances to run several websites and am looking for a way to automatically backup/snapshot instances that would allow me to rollback in the event of a major error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your servers will restart after a reboot, a [snapshot of your VM disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) would make it easy to restore to a previous backup, or to clone a server onto a second host if you want to pre-stage some changes before making them live.

Comment: Sure, but i'm looking for a way of automating/scheduling the snapshots.